# List clipping issue (bug with SwiftUI?)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm having this weird issue with the `List` in macOS Montery Beta 3, where some of the list's items are being clipped, and you have to scroll up and back down to unclip it.

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWZDj.jpg

### Reproduction

1. Create a new blank SwiftUI macOS project
2. Paste the following code:

```
struct Bla: Identifiable {
    var text: String
    var subtext: String
    var id = UUID()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data = (0..<100).map { Bla(text: "Text: \($0)", subtext: "Subtext: \($0)")}
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(data) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.text)
                    Text(item.subtext)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: {
                    var offset = 0
                    for i in 0..<data.count {
                        if i % 2 == 0 {
                            continue
                        }
                        data.remove(at: i - offset)
                        offset += 1
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Run the app, and scroll the list to the middle.
4. Press the plus button on the toolbar. This simply removes half of the items.
5. You should see the clipping issue. Scrolling up and back down fixes it.

Is this something with my code, or with SwiftUI's `List`?

Comment: Using macOS build 21A5284e and it's not replicating.

Comment: @RTXGamer Odd. I'm using the same version and its replicating. What version of Xcode are you using? Also, sometimes it doesn't work, but it works 90% of the time.

Comment: Xcode Version 13.0 beta 3 (13A5192j)

Comment: @RTXGamer Same. Did you make sure to first scroll near the end of the list, before pressing the plus button? It **doesn't work if you are at** the end of the list

Comment: yup scrolled to the bottom and click on the toolbar button, no clipping observed

Comment: @RTXGamer But make sure you're not **all** the way at the bottom. Try half way through the list

Comment: @RTXGamer I added a video to demonstrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the `.listStyle` I dont see the clipping issue anymore, try this:

```
    List(data) { item in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(item.text)
            Text(item.subtext)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
    }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
```

Comment: That works! Thank you so much! Is this a SwiftUI bug?

Comment: @newswiftuser yes it is, it may get fixed in the stable release.

Comment: I really hope so.